# General contract for object comparision : equals() and hashCode()

Tags: java

There is a point in general contract of equals method, which says if You has defined `equals()` method then You should also define `hashCode()` method. And if `o1.equals(o2)` then this is must `o1.hashCode() == o2.hashCode()`.

So my question is what if I break this contract? Where can bring fails the situation when `o1.equals(o2)` but `o1.hashCode != o2.hashCode()` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will lead to unexpected behavior in hash based data structure for example: `HashMap`, [Read how HashTable works](http://javapapers.com/core-java/java-hashtable/)

Comment: unexpected which was not defined that way:), changed by the way

Answer (score 5):

HashMap/HashTable/HashSet/etc will put your object into one of several buckets based on its `hashCode`, and then check to see if any other objects already in that bucket are `equal`.

Because these classes assume the equals/hashCode contract, they won't check for equality against objects in other buckets. After all, any object in another bucket must have a different hashCode, and thus (by the contract) cannot be equal to the object in quesiton. If two objects are `equal` but have different hash codes, they could end up in different buckets, in which case the HashMap/Table/Set/etc won't have a chance to compare them.

So, you could end up with a Set that contains two objects which are equal -- which it's not supposed to do; or a Map that contains two values for the same one key (since the buckets are by key); or a Map where you can't look up a key (since the lookup checks both the hash code and equality); or any number of similar bugs.

Answer (score 4):

If you break the contract, your objects won't work with hash-based containers (and anything else that uses `hashCode()` and relies on its contract).

The basic intuition is as follows: to see whether two objects are the same, the container could call `hashCode()` on both, and compare the results. If the hash codes are different, the container is allowed to short-circuit by assuming that the two objects are not equal.

To give a specific example, if `o1.equals(o2)` but `o1.hashCode() != o2.hashCode()`, you'll likely be able to insert both objects into a `HashMap` (which is meant to store *unique* objects).