# WHY each object in java contains a hashcode number

Tags: java

I just wanted to know WHY each object in java contains a hashcode number. Why each object is assigned a different hashcode generally but two hashcode numbers may have different value.

The rule "The rule ?If two keys are same, there hashcode number will be generated same but if two hashcode numbers are same, there key may be same or different."

Why hashcode number is same if two keys (in hashtable context) are same?

Comment: "Why hashcode number is same if two keys (in hashtable context) are same?" -- because that's what they are used for

Comment: Look up [`Object.hashCode`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()) and [`Object.equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)). Most, if not all, of your questions will be answered.

Comment: possible duplicate of [General contract for object comparision : equals() and hashCode()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14557695/general-contract-for-object-comparision-equals-and-hashcode)

Answer (score 2):

The point of a hash function is to significantly narrow down where you need to look for some particular key.

A very basic example would be in a dictionary, with the hash function of "the first letter in the word": once you've narrowed down your search to the part of the dictionary that starts with that letter, you've knocked out most of the possibilities very efficiently.  Moreover, it's relatively fast to find the part of a dictionary starting with the letter J: much faster than it is to find a specific word directly.

The point of a hash function is to find some specific number associated with a key that is *somewhat* unique: it knocks out *most* possibilities, even if it can't knock out all of them.

Comment: by dictionary do you mean Dictionary Class

Comment: No, I mean a physical book with words.

Answer (score 1):

Each object in Java needs to be able to *produce* a hash code, not necessarily *contain* one.

Hash codes are used for lookups in associative containers, such as hash maps and hash sets. Hash codes do not need to be unique, but when objects are used as keys in hash maps, the more unique the hash codes are - the better. When two keys are the same, then the objects need to be either (1) logically equal, or (2) override `equals` to distinguish between the two objects.

Answer (score 1):

A hashcode is required in many circumstances inside the JDK just because some data structures use it and its properties to work as desired (specifically [`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) and [`HashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html)). This because it is able to identify in a *enough safe* way a specific instance of a class.

A hashcode is a **finite piece of information** (usually of fixed size) so, while you must ensure that the same object will have the same hashcode, you can't ensure that two different objects will have different hashcode. This because **the quantity of information stored in a hashcode is usually smaller than the one contained inside the object that generated it**. What you want is that the probability to have a collision is low enough to work well with the desired algorithms (of course this means that you can't make assumption on uniqueness of hashcode unless in specific situations)

Comment: "many data structures use it" -- What structures? I can only think of hash maps and (maybe) a string-switch.

Comment: Actually there could be many possible implementations of hash maps and hash sets, I was referring to their cluster.

Answer (score 0):

> Why hashcode number is same if two keys are same?

Simply because that is what makes hash tables work!

A hash table works (and is efficient) because it uses the fact that "equal" keys have the same hashcode to cut down the number of keys that it has to look at when you do a lookup.  The semantics of `equals(Object)` and `hashcode()` are defined to work the way that they do so that objects (that conform to the semantic contract ...) can be used as keys in hash tables<sup>1</sup>.

To understand how and why hash tables work, you should probably read a good textbook on algorithms, or read the Wikipedia page on this topic: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table.  They can explain it better than we can ...

---

<sup>1 - There is another precondition ... the hashcode of a key should not change while the key is in use in a hash table.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

```
public int hashCode()
```

Returns a hash code value for the **object**. This method is supported for the benefit of hash tables such as those provided by `HashMap`.(This is typically implemented by converting the internal address of the object into an integer (a 32-bit signed integer))

**The general contract of [hashCode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29):**

- Whenever it is invoked on the same object more than once during an execution of a Java application, the `hashCode` method must consistently return the same `integer`, provided no information used in `equals` comparisons on the object is modified. This integer need not remain *consistent* from one execution of an application to another execution of the same application.
- If two objects are equal according to the [`equals(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) method, then calling the `hashCode` method on each of the two objects must produce the *same integer result*.
  It is not required that if two objects are unequal according to the `equals(java.lang.Object)` method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce *distinct integer results*. However, the programmer should be aware that producing distinct integer results for *unequal objects* may improve the performance of hash tables.
- it is necessary to override the `hashCode` method whenever this `equals()` method is overridden, so as to maintain the general contract for the `hashCode` method, which states that equal objects must have equal hash codes.

**Note:** 4,294,967,296 (2^32) possible hashCodes are available, but number of objects we are creating are much larger, so some objects must share the same hash code.
[Reference1](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6321873)
[Reference2](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6809470)